# Python uninstalled itself and will not reinstall

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation

Sorry about the title

**Brief Description of problem:**

- Went to open Python 2.7.11 (IDLE) as normal and an installation
  screen showed up.
- *Was* already installed, but ran with it as I needed to use 2.7
- Got an  error saying: Please insert the disk
- Tried to uninstall (to reinstall fully). Same error
- Tried to install Python 2.7.11 into a different dir. same error
- Tried the repair option...same problem
- Went into add/remove programs to try uninstalling fully. Same thing occurs

**System:**

Windows 10, 64bit, (Partners laptop - Toshiba Satellite)

**Exact Error Messages:**

1. There is a problem with this Windows Installer Package.
   A program required for this install to complete could not be run.
   Contact your support personnel or package vendor
2. Please insert Disc

**Other details:**

The installation file I am using was downloaded directly from Python Downloads main site.
So I went and got a new copy, only to be faced with the same problem ....
The installation/version(msi installer or setup package)

I have the same one I used to install originally, saved on a USB and I have used it across a few systems.

I then tried a previous version (2.7.10 would have been fine) but unfortunately I get the same thing.

When I attempt to install I get error message 2 from above.
When I attempt to repair or remove I get error message 1 from above

**Reason I need this sorted:**
Most of my code-base up to now (about 80% of it) is written and running in Python 2.7.11. Although I have and use 3.5, and it runs smoothly this is not an option for me, I am not prepared to edit all of that code. I know that some things may not need editing, but most will need tweaks of some sort.

I have another system with 2.7, but this particular computer is my partners and I spend a lot of my free time using it.

My solution at the moment is that I am using a Raspberry Pi now as my main system. It is a bit of a nightmare lugging keyboard, mouse, Pi, etc back and forth, and my GF's laptop has a cracked screen so it's outputting its display through a VGA screen. The problem is that the Pi needs to use the same screen so I cant have both on at the same time. And the Pi isn't efficient enough to become my main internet and programming system. I know there are little solutions to these trivial issues but my preference, is to just get 2.7 working on the laptop again...problems solved!

**Was I doing anything out of the ordinary?**

Short answer = NO
I literally just double clicked my IDLE desktop icon one morning, and it brought up the installation screen. I had been coding with it the night before. I have a few little projects but nothing complex, on this System I run just a few additional modules compared to my Linux systems. I mostly just use bare python and it's included modules.

I have never edited the C:\Python27 directory other than saving the odd script  into it for convenience.

One thing I should add. Something I did do a while back using 2.7 that involved Python27's contents. I didn't modify, remove, or rename, or change a single file or folder in this directory. But I did do the following:

I copied everything from this directory and pasted into another in the C: dir. in order to get past Windows prevention methods, to run a Mechanize script on this Windows system. A short demonstration I was doing for a talk. This was about 3 months ago and I have been using Python 2.7.11 on a daily basis since then with no problems. As far as I can see there is no reason for this to be happening.

Any advice regarding this would be very much appreciated.

**Note:**
I have tried my absolute best to word this right and cover everything I can see to relevant to the problem. I apologize for the title of the question and if required to sum this up into a simple question it would be 2 questions:
Why did Python 2.7.11 uninstall itself?
Why can't I re-install it?
I hope I covered everything appropriately, my first experience with this service was negative. I worded something in simple terms and got grilled for it, and almost banned from asking questions!
I welcome any feedback on the way I approached this question. I find this site a very useful resource and want to use it as efficiently as possible - and of course provide the best account of the situation to get the best answers.

Ben

Comment: Even with this very detailed explanation it may prove quite difficult to solve your problem. There can still be a dozen of reasons why things went 'wrong'.  Missing some specifics though: "an installation screen showed up"  what did it say exactly? What exactly did you do with it? "Please insert the disk"  this is a very generic message, it was probably more specific. What exactly did it say? Did you install off of an usb stick?  "The installation file" which file did you get *exactly*?

Comment: It was literally "insert disk" or "please insert disk" there seems to be a random occurrence of the 2 error messages, either I get one or the other, but when I either try to repair, install, or uninstall I will be faced with one of them. It's really frustrating because most of my learning has been in Python 2.7 and although I use 3 now and then, the last day or 2 I have been tripped up by silly things. I want to get 2.7 running ideally. I will maybe just keep trying installers ov back versions until hopefully one works!

Comment: Sorry - just saw the rest of the reply - the installation I originally used (that has been working fine for several months) is Python 2.7.11 64 bit MSI from the official python.org/downloads site:https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Do you have another computer where you can test the MSI on? It sounds to me that something is corrupting your MSI download.  Also, are you sure you should be using the 64-bits version? Perhaps the original installation was the 32-bits version. I'm pretty sure you'll need to use the 32 bits MSI to remove/repair/reinstall if you originally installed a 32 bits version of Python. (note that this is the default download that is offered, even when you're on a 64-bits windows)

Comment: Not another Windows one - but here's an odd thing...I ran Python in CMD or Dos, the Windows Terminal environment, just out of curiosity and 2.7 still runs  - eg when I enter: >>> python into the terminal to run a shell environment, the documentation that shows is 2.7.9, Then I carried on my quest and went back with the versions...got to 2.7.6 and it installed, but without IDLE. I think I will just use the RasPi for now it is less of a headache. Thank you

Comment: If you're juggling various installed python versions at the same time you could also have a PATH  issue perhaps, try removing all traces to python from your PATH environment variable(s) and if it exists, PYTHONPATH as well

Comment: regardless, the latest 2.7 MSI should be able to install just fine even with existing pythons on the system.  Perhaps you should look into microsoft windows solutions for repairing a broken existing MSI installation that prevents new (un)installs?  There's quite a few hits and things to try when googling for that